# Zoom in and out with touch in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin and trying to create a simple page. I have scrollLayout and grid inside. In the grid I have a frame and some text in frame. I deployed it on my andriod but when i try to enlarge the screen with touch(two fingers) it doesnt enlarge the screen. I want user to enlarge the text and read. Any help would be appreciated please..

Answer (score 1):

Scroll layout doesn't have the feature for zooming in/zooming out entire view. It just scrolls your content when not fitting screen height / width.

To achieve effect you want you need two things:

- Pinch zoom gesture support (https://github.com/twintechs/TwinTechsFormsLib, http://www.mrgestures.com)
- Label.ScaleTo or Label.FontSize properties which are controlled with your gesture.